# Get rid of pre-selection in catia

Tags: vba, catia

Im currently creating a macro in catia that goes through each capture and screenshots them. It highlights the name and center graphs it in the specification tree. However, once it's been highlighted it will stay highlighted. It looks like this:

Captures in the specification tree are highlighted in a light blue color

[image: 1]

I've tried pressing esc or using ActiveDocument.Selection.Clear but none of those works. Im not sure why this happens or how to clear it.

The code is highlighted by adding it to the document selection, by either:

```
CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Add ActiveDocument.AnnotationSets.Item(1).Captures.Item(1)
```

or selection search

```
CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Search "'Functional Tolerancing & Annotations'.Capture"
```

So im not sure how that would make a difference

Comment: How do you highlight the name of the capture? (may be show a code snippet)

Comment: @Shrotter I just edited the post for you to see

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. For me _Clear_ works for selected captures.